# Checking irreducibility of a degree $6$ polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I want to check whether the following polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$:
$$f(X)=X^6+X^5+X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$$

One obvious way to solve the problem is to divide $f(X)$ by irreducible polynomials of smaller degree.

My question:

Is there any other clever way to check whether this polynomial is irreducible or not?

Comment: A *slightly* more clever way is to divide it by the irreducible polynomials of degree 2 and 3. There's no need to divide by those of degree 4 or 5 (why?), and there's an easier way to address those of degree 1 (what?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a cyclotomic polynomial. Its zeros are the seventh roots of unity
over $\Bbb F_3$. But these generate the field $\Bbb F_{3^k}$
where $3^k$ is the least power of $3$ with $3^k\equiv1$ (mod~$7$).
The polynomial is irreducible iff $k=6$. Is it?

Comment: (+1) $3$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(7\mathbb{Z})^*$, so I would say so.